# Drivers on AMD Rembrandt broken after latest update on Linux 22.04.2

Tags: drivers, 22.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I updated yesterday and my GPU drivers seem to not work anymore.

It seems like the problem is with some of the NVIDIA drivers, since the AMD ones are in place.

All info logs:

```
$ uname -r 
5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency        

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
33:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt (rev d1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 50b4
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

$ inxi -CSG
System:
  Host: veromontanaro-ThinkPad-T14s-Gen-3
    Kernel: 5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6850U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP cache: L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1520 min/max: 1600/4767 cores: 1: 1600 2: 1600 3: 1397
    4: 1600 5: 1348 6: 1600 7: 1600 8: 1600 9: 1600 10: 1600 11: 1397 12: 1600
    13: 1396 14: 1392 15: 1397 16: 1600
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Rembrandt driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Luxvisions Innotech Integrated RGB Camera type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: REMBRANDT (rembrandt LLVM 15.0.6 DRM 3.47
  5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5


$ dkms status
nvidia/525.116.04, 5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency, x86_64: installed


$ dpkg -l |grep nvidia
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                            510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-525:amd64                            525.116.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-530:amd64                            530.30.02-0ubuntu1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  linux-headers-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency            5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency              5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Signed kernel image nvidia-lowlatency
ii  linux-modules-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency            5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-510-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency 5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.19.0-1010
ii  linux-nvidia-5.19-headers-5.19.0-1010                  5.19.0-1010.10                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.19.0
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-510-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency 5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.19.0-1010 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency  5.19.0-1010.10                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-510                               510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-525                               525.116.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-530                               530.30.02-0ubuntu1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-525                                        525.116.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-530                                        530.30.02-0ubuntu1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-510                               510.108.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-525                               525.116.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-530                               530.30.02-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-prime                                           0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
rc  nvidia-settings                                        530.30.02-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-525                                       525.116.04-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
```

Currently, i am not able to access Software&Updates -> Additional Drivers, as i am getting a blank screen.
I tried reinstalling the nvidia packages but it didn't work, and i would like to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu.

I really hope i can find a solution, as AMD Rembrandts are pretty new on the market, thus making it hard to find documentation.

EDIT: i also checked the output of `cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log`

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-530
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-525srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-525
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-515srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-515
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-510
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-470srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-470
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-450srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel/nvidia-390
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:1681
BusID "PCI:51@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:33:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

It seems like both amdgpu and nvidia are unloaded, which i didnt'expect to be. Moreover, noveau is somehow blacklisted. Question remains, what to do now?